# Trouble accessing child divs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple divs and I'm attempting to do a function when a user mouses over the divs. Inside of the divs there can be any number of "child" divs and I need to access them within the function. I don't seem to be able to do this. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<div id='div_test'  onmouseover='modelMouseOver2()' onmouseout='modelMouseOut()'>

        <div id = "model1"><img src="img/circle.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div id = "model2" class='models' onmouseover="modelMouseOver2()" onmouseout="model2MouseOut()" style=" width: 40px; height: 40px;"><img src="img/circle2.png" alt=""  />
            <div><img src="img/circle3.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="img/circle4.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="img/circle2.png" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
        <div id = "model3" class='models' onmouseover="modelMouseOver2()"><img src="img/circle3.png" alt=""  /></div>
        <div id = "model4" class='models' onmouseover="modelMouseOver2()"><img src="img/circle4.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div id = "model5" class='models' onmouseover="modelMouseOver2()"><img src="img/circle5.png" alt="" /></div>

    </div>
```

for The script:

```
function modelMouseOver2() {
// I'm not sure what to do here to access the child divs.
$(this).children("div").each(function (i) {
    $(this).hide();
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in:

```
function modelMouseOver2() {
// I'm not sure what to do here to access the child divs.
$(this).children("div").each(function (i) { // here
    $(this).hide();
});
}
```

The first "this" refers to the DOM window.

You have two options here. The first is to pass in `this` in the inline event, the second being just to set the event in javascript:

**Inline:**

```
<div id='div_test'  onmouseover='modelMouseOver2(this)' onmouseout='modelMouseOut()'>
```

and the javascript for inline:

```
function modelMouseOver2(xthis) {
// I'm not sure what to do here to access the child divs.
$(xthis).children("div").each(function (i) {
    $(this).hide();
});
}
```

**Or, setting the onmouseover via javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('div_test').onmouseover=modelMouseOver2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).find("div").hide();
```

But if you started using jQuery you may subscribe to your events on document load using jQuery itself:

```
$(function() {
    $('div#div_test').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('div').hide();
    }, function() { 
        $(this).find('div').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try a js like this

```
(function($){
   $('#div_test').hover(
      function(){
           // this is the mouse over 
           // this selects all the div inside
           $(this).find('div');
      },
      function(){
           // this is the mouse out
           // this selects all the div inside
           $(this).find('div');
      }

   );
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do some thing like this

```
$(this).find("div").each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
```